# problem with UFW

Tags: ufw

Following [this tutorial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics) I executed the following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install ufw

 sudo ufw allow ssh

 sudo ufw allow http

 sudo ufw enable

 sudo ufw status verbose
```

and I get:

```
 Status: active

 Logging: on (low)

 Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)

 New profiles: skip


 To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Ssh is working, but browser can't reach my page!
when I disable ufw (sudo ufw disable) then my browser can access apache.

Can someone explain me what's happening with ufw?

Comment: Have you rebooted after making the changes?

Comment: yes I rebooted the whole server. Unfortunately still doesn't work!

Comment: Is your webserver actually listening on port 80, or is it on some non-default port? check with `sudo netstat -nlpt | grep apache`

Comment: result: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7961/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7961/apache2